# How to encode a video file for real time streaming and deliver it through UDP datagrams

Tags: c, video, udp, video-streaming, video-encoding

I am working on a P2P system for real time video streaming.
I would like to know how to encode the source file, which is a video, in order to deliver it in real time by encapsulating the encoded content in custom UDP datagrams.

Which video formats are more suitable for real time video streaming?

How can I encode at the source and decode at the destination the video?

Is there any utility to do that in C?

Which video player could I use to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I am just curious if you have done any research of your own on this? Have you come across any tools that you are considering? Why have you chosen C?

Comment: Why custom? Why not use [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) or something similar?

Comment: I am continuing the work started by someone else (this is the subject of my internship), this means there are some decisions that were already taken and I cannot change them. Custom UDP packets and C are two of them.

Comment: Well the quality of the video needs to be considered, but that said 2 popular streaming formats at the moment are [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) and [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/). H.264 is currently royalty free but there is a possibility of that changing in the future, worth reading up on but I'm sure you would be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know something about how to integrate these codecs in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can check this one also:**

ffmpeg takes care of all the hard work of video processing by doing all the decoding, encoding, muxing and demuxing for you. This can make media applications much simpler to write. It's simple, written in C, fast, and can decode almost any codec you'll find in use today, as well as encode several other formats

ffmpeg Documentation
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

UDP prototype streaming system(but old)
http://sys.cs.pdx.edu/trac/Cascades/browser/Trunk/Misc/Video/Codec/Misc/AVCodec/Source/FFMpeg-SVN-7063/libavformat/udp.c

C Code

http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding_8c-source.html

http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html

Comment: Thank you very much! These resources seem to be what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi Elnaz, I was wondering if choosing ffmpeg as tool for decoding and encoding is a good choice even in case the program should run on Windows as well. What do you think about it? Thanks!

Comment: @pAkY88 Hi, actually I don't think there is any problem just compiling FFmpeg on Windows is not too easy. you can use this tutorial http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/